# Why can't I see all of my projects in VS 2017 from TFS 2017?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I have about 24 TFS projects, all of which I can see just fine from VS 2013. But when I connect using VS2017 Enterprise I can only see 7 of them. This happens intermittently and up until today it seemed to resolve itself fairly quickly, but today I'm not having any luck. I've checked the projects that I can see vs. the ones that I cannot and the security seems to be the same. I'm a Collection Admin so I should be able to see everything.

For reference this used to happen before the upgrade to TFS2017 when we were on TFS 2013 as well.

Any idea what could be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind – I figured it out. When connecting to a team project I need to select all of the projects before clicking on Connect. Not sure why I can’t just click on the top-level collection like I can in 2013, but that’s the way it works…